# How to write down this name?

Tags: names

Is there an english name or English translation that matches the following voice recording?
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62131673/audio/endesuelax2.wav

The name might be Russian or Ukrainian.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about translation. Please see the [help/on-topic] for more information

Comment: This isn't a Russian or a Ukrainian name or even a word recognized by Ukrainian or Russian speaking people, unfortunately. The pronunciation in the recording definitely does not sound Eastern-Slavic. Just curious: where did you take this recording from?

Comment: It was a translation job I had to do, one of the interviewed women had this name, you can hear it here:
https://youtu.be/fFQjgpSv8LI?t=31

Comment: Oksana is really a common Ukrainian name (and it sounds much Ukrainian: Russians pronounce it as Aksana). Maria is really one of the most well-known names ever. But the third name, only if it's a Ukrainian or a Russian lady, is probably a misheard hard-spoken introduction phrase "And this is Slava". Slava can be a personal name or a hypocorism of Myroslava, or much more rare Mstyslava, Rostyslava, etc, in Ukraine. But, to me, it sounds much more like Slawa -- a Polish equivalent of the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably write it as Endiswalla or just Endiswal.

If you "had to" make an "English nickname" it would be Andrew, maybe.

(Purely FWIW, to me it sounds like an Indian-English speaker. As mentioned by Lyubomyr, it surely has nothing to do with Russian.)